# Is it possible to find out mac user account login history

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, user-account

I have given my mac book to my friend.

I have created new account to him and gave the credentials for it.

I have a doubt what if my friend logged into my account by guessing my password.

It's an easy password.

*So I would like to know if my friend managed to login to my mac user account ?*

*so if there's any history stored somewhere, I can confirm yeah my friend did login in to my account or else I can be rest assured.*

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

To see your login history on your Mac:

1. Open **Terminal**.
2. Type the word `last` followed by your username. For example: `last udhyantimilsina`
3. A list of login activity for your user account will appear in reverse chronological order.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer I figured out by myself. Go to **System preferences** > **Screen Time** > **App usage**. It informs you on how much time ⏱ was spent on the screen.

If he used your account you should see a gray bar , which indicates how much time was spent.